# Installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on NVME disk and then previous Ubuntu on SSD disk won't start

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu

How to fix the problem in topic? The latest installation was done from a USB stick using boot option in BIOS saying UEFI for the USB stick

Both Ubuntu installations are Kubuntu 22.04.1.

update-grub:

```
sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda2
Found Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid on /dev/sdc2
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Comment: Does os-prober found your previous install `sudo update-grub` please.

Comment: I have now added the update-grub output to the question.